# Orchard CMS - Azure Media Services

Tags: azure, orchardcms, azure-media-services

I've followed the User Guide availiable [here](https://msopentech.com/blog/2014/04/08/streamlined-video-content-management-with-orchard-and-azure/)

When I watch the preview of my video, on Admin panel it's okay.

The problem occur when I insert my media on my page, I get this error when I access the page:

```
502 - Web server received an invalid response while acting as a gateway or proxy server.
```

This is a super generic error and I'm completly lost in how to follow the error in order to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a timeout issue, try to increase the timeout in the configuration:

```
<system.web>
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="102400" executionTimeout="3600" />
```